# POST json using Python: non-serializable error?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Trying to post json to the specified URL using requests:

```
import requests, glob, unicodedata, ntpath, time, json

url = 'https://myWebsite.com/ext/ext/ext'

json_file = open("/Users/ME/Documents/folder/folder/test.json")

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(json_file), headers=headers)
```

This gives me the following error, however:

```
TypeError: <open file '/Users/ME/Documents/folder/folder/test.json', mode 'r' at 0x1021c9660> is not JSON serializable
```

What causes this error? I know my json file is valid json so I don't think that is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to *produce* JSON if you already have valid JSON text in a file. Just send the file contents:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json_file, headers=headers)
```

This will send the file contents of the open file as a POST body, streaming the data efficiently.

`json.dumps()` is only needed if you have Python objects (such as strings, numbers, booleans, dictionaries, lists, etc.) that need to be represented as a JSON string.

Comment: It sounds useful to me.

Answer (score 2):

`open` does not return the content of the file, but a file object. try calling `read()` on the returned value of `open` to get the actual contents.

See your own error:

```
TypeError: <open file '/Users/ME/Documents/folder/folder/test.json', mode 'r' at 0x1021c9660> is not JSON serializable
```

It says that you're passing an OPEN FILE instead of an array of values. Besides, if you want to open the file and send it's contents, the file is NOT a json object so `json.dumps()` will reencode your content.

If you want to validate your json code prior to sending it, you should:

```
text = open("your/file.json").read()
try:
    validated = json.dumps(json.loads(text))
    r = requests.post(url, data=validated, headers=headers)
except TypeError as e:
    #blablabla
```

Comment: You don't need to call `.read()` at all in this case. `data` takes a file object, it'll be streamed as an efficient upload.

Comment: Yes it does, but json.dumps does not expect a file as parameter. that's why I meant to use .read() for json. after that, i suggested a json revalidation

Comment: Nope, but that's just a misunderstanding what `json.dumps()` is *for*.

Comment: Yes, but that's a different error. My suggested solution was because I thought he wanted to revalidate the json content in the file.

Comment: The OP writes: *I know my json file is valid json so I don't think that is the problem.*

Comment: And why not use `json.dumps(json.load(json_file))` instead of reading the file into memory first?

Comment: very good point :p. forgot `load` (without the `s`) 's existence